# cassandra-cql: How to determine if the Result return 0 record

Tags: cql

I have following function to check if a rowkey exist in a columnfamily.
I used following command to get the result from SELECT statement.
indexes = db.execute("SELECT * FROM #{$configuration} WHERE key = '#{index_config}'")

What should I do with the indexes result to say that the above select statement find nothing?

I used to use "return false if indexes.size == 0" but it not work. indexes.size is 1 although there is now row found.

I try to check "return false if index[1].to_s.empty?" but it does not work either.

```
def self.index_config_exists?(config, keyspace, columnfamily)
index_config = "#{keyspace}_#{columnfamily}_#{config}_idx"
db = CassandraCQL::Database.new($cassandra_host, {:keyspace => $indexing})
indexes = db.execute("SELECT * FROM #{$configuration} WHERE key = '#{index_config}'")
db.disconnect!()

indexes.fetch {|index|
  # check if the index configuration not empty
  puts index.to_s
  puts index[0]
  puts index[1].class
  return false if index[1].to_s.empty?
}

return true
```

end